# NPM init error log file details - in creating package.json file

Tags: json, npm

I am new to learning node.js and copying and pasting the details of the npm-debug.txt file here:

How do I best describe this error and how can I fix it?

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'init' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.11
3 info using node@v0.10.20
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 silly package data undefined
6 info init written successfully
7 error Error: canceled
7 error     at Interface.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read\lib\read.js:66:13)
7 error     at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
7 error     at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:620:16)
7 error     at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
7 error     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
7 error     at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
7 error     at ReadStream.onData (readline.js:840:14)
7 error     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
7 error     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
7 error     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
8 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
8 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
8 error or email it to:
8 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
9 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
10 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "init"
11 error cwd C:\web-design\node.js\node_modules
12 error node -v v0.10.20
13 error npm -v 1.3.11
14 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score -2):

It looks that there is a bug on your code. Check that out.

Comment: Totally new to stackoverflow.com - I can't post screenshots yet.
Totally beginner question, but please help me find out where the bug is located?